# MySQL and Windows 10, I receive an error "The server is configured with lower_case_table_names=1..."

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Server 5.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE on Windows 10. I have sifted through several pages of questions related to this on multiple websites, including Stack Overflow, but cannot figure out where I can amend the server so that it is is configured with lower_case_table_names=2, rather than lower_case_table_names=1.

Many answers I have seen point to finding either a file ending in 'my.ini' or 'my.cnf', neither of which I can locate on my disc. Truthfully speaking, I am a beginner with SQL, and had difficulty understanding the tutorial page that many users have pointed to, which is:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Virtually every resource I am learning from references uppercase table names, columns, etc., which is why I want to use uppercase versus lowercase.

For example, if I create a table called **EmployeeInfo** and a few columns, I get this error when I click "Apply":

```
Apply Changes to Object

The server is configured with lower_case_table_names=1, which only allows lowercase characters in schema and table names. The object will be created as 'employeeinfo'.
```

I want the table to be called **EmployeeInfo**. I do not want it to be in lowercase. However, I cannot locate the supposed 'my.ini', or 'my.cnf' files that have been mentioned in other answers pertaining to this question.

Or is it a best practice to get used to using lowercase font as you move further with SQL?

**EDIT:**

I believe I have located the so-called 'my.ini' file, although, there is no 'ini' file type. It is labeled 'Configuration settings'.

However, I cannot find anything related to 'lower_case_table_name=1' inside after searching.

**EDIT 2:**

I found the 'lower_case_table_names' option in the System Options File and changed it to '2'.

However, when I click 'Apply', it tells me:

**Could not Save Configuration File**

The error looks like this:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwryL.png)

Comment: Did you check parameter with "SHOW VARIABLES" command?

Comment: Look here to finde the configuration file location: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where would I check that parameter?

Comment: So I found the 'Data' folder after reinstalling MySQL and putting it in my 'Program Files' folder rather than a 'ProgramData' folder, which was seemingly invisible on my computer. There is an 'auto.cnf' file, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is with Docker itself when you upgrade to latest release, This happened with me when upgraded. Try to downgrade Docker to your earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 specs seem to generally [recommend sticking with lowercase table names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

> ...To avoid problems caused by such differences, it is best to adopt a
>   consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to
>   databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is
>   recommended for maximum portability and ease of use...

Anyways, here is how you view that variable setting:

```
SHOW variables like 'lower_case_table_names';
```

And here is how you change that variable setting to allow your CamelCase:

```
lower_case_table_names = 1 (<- put in your mysql config file)
restart mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, gfunk! However, wouldn't I want to change it to 'lower_case_table_names=2'?

Also, when I run the query:

SET global lower_case_table_names=2;

I get this error:

'Error Code: 1238: Variable 'lower_case_table_names' is a read only variable.'

Comment: Yea my bad (i'm not sure if its to be set to 0 or 2 but def not 1) - I'll test out and edit that post. And yea may have to edit the mysql config file and restart...

Comment: Thanks, gfunk. May you check my second edit in my original post? I think I found out where I have to go, but there is a final step that is throwing an error.

Comment: I dunno sorry man. Looks like a Windows file permission error - I'd personally just make a backup copy of the file then manually edit it, or search StackOverflow for that specific file permission error... I'm using Ubuntu so i just `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`, pasted in the line, then `service mysql restart` (i tested and it worked on my OS, updated my post accordingly)

Comment: All good. Thanks for your help. I actually opened Workbench as the administrator (right click run as administrator, even though I am my computer's administrator) and that let me change it. However, even when I create a table after setting lower_case_table_names to 2 and applying it, it still doesn't work. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error on MySql 8.0 and with Windows 10 by doing the following: -

1. I started MySQl Workbench CE as an adminstrator
2. I changed the Windows directory path attributes for: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0", from "Read Only" to "Full/Write"
3. In the MYSQL Workbench Window, I selected "Local Instance MYSQL80" tab
4. On the left-side of the window, I went to "Navigator" - "Instance" - "Options File"
5. In the Options window I went to "General" - "System"
6. I clicked on "lower_case_table_names". I left the attribute at 0
7. If you look 3 items below, you will see "offline_mode". Make sure it is ticked
8. Lastly, I clicked the "Apply" button

Everything went through! Reboot MySQL - just to make sure!

*Please note that I am not sure if it was necessary to make changes to the ini source directory attributes at point number "2"!  Please test by changing the directory attributes back to "Read"!